# Wobbly windows disappeared

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, kde, effects

OS: Kubuntu 18.04 with all recent updates. I've installed Latte Dock, also latest released version.

I've also have nVidia GeForce 1080Ti with drivers, installed from the graphics-drivers PPA (respective line in sources.list is `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic main`)

Yesterday, I've got crashes in the Latte Dock, and Wobbly windows effect disappeared after them. It has happened in the evening, so I've powered my computer off and gone home.

Today, when I've turned it on and updated drivers, there is no such item in the settings (System Settings -> Desktop Behavior -> Desktop Effects).